# In Perforce, how to find files with certain filetype+attribute?

Tags: perforce

Files stored in P4 depot are decorated with file type and optional attributes:

[image]

The above example is for `<binary+S4>`.

**How can I search the depot tree for all files which have `<binary+S4>`?**

I want to audit these files and change attributes of some of them to **`<binary+S10>`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line (I'm on Windows using Cygwin's version of "grep" and "cut", should work on Mac/Unix too):

```
p4 -F %type%:%depotFile% files //... | grep ^binary+S4 | cut -d: -f2- | p4 -x - edit -t +S10
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check somewhat later, because I found out that my `p4` command is broken and I don't have time to fix it at the moment. Also it is possible that I'll need to find a less elegant solution (without the Cygwin) where listing of items (without changing file type, just an audit) is enough.

Answer (score 5):

p4 [fstat](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_fstat.html) should solve it for you.

So a command like this would show you all of the writable text files.
`p4 fstat -F "headType=text+w" //DEPOT/...`

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll keep previous answer accepted, because it also shows changing the attribute, but for pure detection of files yours is more suitable, because it works without 3rd-party tools.